# 'Object' has no attribute 'function name'

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm using an XML callback tag to update the values in my python code.

```
<import>import folder.filename</import>
<make>folder.filename.class($s1)</make>
<callback>set_foo($s1)</callback>
```

The `set_foo` function is presnt in my python code, but I still get the error at the point of calling that my class `Object` has **no attribute** `set_foo`.

```
def set_foo(self, a):
    print a
```

Comment: Is this some library you are using? If so, it would be advised to add the tag of that library to the question

Comment: @AnandSKumar I'm using Wx framework. I have added that tag. I'm not sure if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused due to improper indentation. 
Indenting the following code in the corresponding Class resolved the problem in my case.

```
def set_foo(self, a):
    print a
def __init__(self, x):
    self.set_foo(x)
```